# Key based access for the Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Lets say the API endpoint to GET a list of users is this

```
/api_auth/user/
```

But I want to restrict access to this list only to people with an **api_key**

```
 /api_auth/user/?access_key=$omeRandomHash3252532
```

How do I implement such an access system using the Django Rest Framework?

Should I use Permissions to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box for django-rest-framework, however it can easily be implemented:

If you take a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ you'll see an Example of a custom authentication method. Baased on that, you'll need to implement something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class APIKeyAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        api_key = request.GET.get('api_key')
        if not api_key:
            return None

        try:
            user = get_user_from_api_key(api_key)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No user for API KEY')

        return (user, None)
```

The `APIKeyAuthentication` should be put on an authentication.py module and be configured with `REST_FRAMEWORK` setting on settings.py, like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'my_custom_package.authentication.APIKeyAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Now, what the above does is that it checks if the `api_key` parameter is present (if not it will return None to check if the request can be authenticated differently -- if you don't want to check any other authentication classes then just raise an `exceptions.AuthenticationFailed` exception like we do when we dont find the user below. Now, we need to implement a `get_user_from_api_key` function that will return a `User` instance from an API_KEY. If the user that is correlated with the passed api_key is found then it will be returned, if not an `exceptions.AuthenticationFailed`exception will be thrown.

Concerning the `get_user_from_api_key` function, its implementation depends on your requirements. For instance, if you want to create a new api key for each user, you should create an `APIKey` model that will have an `api_key` `CharField` and a `ForeignKey` to the `User` that has this `api_key`. The `get_user_from_api_key` function then will query the `APIKey` model to get the user with the provided `api_key`.

**Update**

If you want to use the django-rest-framework permissions instead of the authentication, you may create an `APIKeyPermission` class like this:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class APIKeyPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        api_key = request.GET.get('api_key')
        return check_permission(api_key, request)
```

Where the `check_permission` function will check if the api_key passed has permissions for that specific request. Please check the examples on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ for more info - you may instead choose to implement `has_object_permission` to implement object-level permissions instead of view-level permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have a feeling that I might need to use Permissions to implement this. Please check the edit in the question.

Comment: Are you referring to django permission or django-rest-framework permissions ?

Comment: Hey, this works. Any idea how I can add this to all my APIViews ?

Comment: > should be put on an authentication.py module and be configured

@Serafeim where do this file exist? I could not find it.

Comment: @volatil3, nowhere, it's a module you'll add yourself :)

Comment: @Serafeim thanks for the reply, I rather tried View Based permission by doing `permission_classes = (CheckAPI,)` and rather checking `api_key` header I got `Authentication credentials were not provided.`. I only passed `api_key` header

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to set a header in your request you can use [Rest Framework's Token Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

Otherwise, if you need to put it in the URL as a `GET`-paramter you could make your own [custom authentication class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication):

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication


class MyAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('api-key', None)
        if token is None:
            return None
        return self.authenticate_credentials(token)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have a feeling that I might need to use Permissions to implement this. Please check the edit in the question.

Comment: Maybe explain why "you have the feeling" that you need permissions?

Comment: I don't want to tie this access mechanism to a particular user but to all the requests made to the API.

Comment: Ok sounds like you should use permissions!

Comment: Any idea how I can add a single Custom Permission across all the APIViews?

Comment: Use `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy